# PERL tk module handling

Tags: perl, user-interface, checkbox, tk-toolkit

I am using tk module to build a checklist for user to choose. I am totally beginner to this module. Currently the checklist created is all in the same series column, since it will be a long list, any idea how could I separate few of the options to another column? Also, any idea how to align those text to the left while checkbox to the right? To display it cleanly and neatly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Tk;


$main = MainWindow->new();
$label = $main->Label(-text => "Presence Check");

$label->pack();
$frame = $main->Frame(-relief=>"groove", -borderwidth=>2);
#$frame = $main->Frame(-relief=>"groove", -borderwidth=>2)->pack(-side => 'top', -expand => 1, -fill =>'both');
#$frame = $main->Frame->pack(-side => 'left', -fill => 'x');



$check1 = $frame->Checkbutton(-text=>"Document A (docx, pdf)",
                          -variable=>\$a,
                  -onvalue=>"APRESENT",
                  -offvalue=>"AABSENT");

#$check1->pack(-side=>"top");
$check2 = $frame->Checkbutton(-text=>"Document B (xlsx)",
                          -variable=>\$b,
                  -onvalue=>"BPRESENT",
                  -offvalue=>"BABSENT");

$check2->pack(-side=>"top");

$check3 = $frame->Checkbutton(-text=>"C specification",
                          -variable=>\$c,
                  -onvalue=>"CPRESENT",
                  -offvalue=>"CABSENT");

$check3->pack(-side=>"top");

$check4 = $frame->Checkbutton(-text=>"A-Specification",
                          -variable=>\$aspec,
                  -onvalue=>"ASPECPRESENT",
                  -offvalue=>"ASPECSABSENT");

$check4->pack(-side=>"top");

$check5 = $frame->Checkbutton(-text=>"Important Report",
                          -variable=>\$report,
                  -onvalue=>"REPORTPRESENT",
                  -offvalue=>"REPORTSABSENT");

$check5->pack(-side=>"top");

$check6 = $frame->Checkbutton(-text=>"Handbook",
                          -variable=>\$handbook,
                  -onvalue=>"HANDBOOKPRESENT",
                  -offvalue=>"HANDBOOKABSENT");

$check6->pack(-side=>"top");

$check7 = $frame->Checkbutton(-text=>"Data Spreadsheet",
                          -variable=>\$dataxls,
                  -onvalue=>"DATAPRESENT",
                  -offvalue=>"DATAABSENT");

$check7->pack(-side=>"top");

$check8 = $frame->Checkbutton(-text=>"D file",
                          -variable=>\$dfile,
                  -onvalue=>"DFILEPRESENT",
                  -offvalue=>"DFILEABSENT");

$check8->pack(-side=>"top");


$check10 = $frame->Checkbutton(-text=>"xx doc",
                          -variable=>\$xxdoc,
                  -onvalue=>"XXDOCPRESENT",
                  -offvalue=>"XXDOCABSENT");

$check10->pack(-side=>"top");

$check18 = $frame->Checkbutton(-text=>"yy Doc",
                          -variable=>\$yydoc,
                  -onvalue=>"YYDOCPRESENT",
                  -offvalue=>"YYDOCABSENT");

$check18->pack(-side=>"top");
$frame->pack();

$button = $main->Button(-text => "Exit",
                        -command => \&exit_button);
$button->pack();
MainLoop();

sub exit_button {
print "$a $b $c $aspec $report $handbook $dataxls $dfile $xxdoc $yydoc \n";
#print "$rv\n";
exit,
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `strict` and `warnings` and declare variables with `my`, see [Perl Maven](https://perlmaven.com/always-use-strict-and-use-warnings) blog post for more information

Comment: If you ahve a specific reason for `Tk` then so be it, otherwise i'd recommend `Gtk3` instead

Comment: *"any idea how could I separate few of the options to another column?"* : See [The grid Geometry Manager](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/tk/ch02_02.htm) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... any idea how could I separate few of the options to another
>   column? Also, any idea how to align those text to the left while
>   checkbox to the right?

Here is an example of how you can use the grid geometry manager to align the labels and checkboxes:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new();
my @label_texts = (
    "Document A (docx, pdf)",
    "Document B (xlsx)",
    "C specification"
);

my @labels;
my @checkvars;
my @check_buttons;
for my $text ( @label_texts ) {
    my $label = $mw->Label(-text => $text);
    push @labels, \$label;
    my $check_var;
    my $check = $mw->Checkbutton(
        -text=>"",
        -variable=>\$check_var,
    );
    push @checkvars, \$check_var;
    push @check_buttons, \$check;
    Tk::grid($label, $check, -sticky => 'w');
}

my $button = $mw->Button(
    -text => "Exit",
    -command => \&exit_button
);
Tk::grid($button, "-");

MainLoop();

sub exit_button {
    for my $i (0..$#checkvars) {
        my $var = $checkvars[$i];
        my $state = $$var;
        $state = 'undef' if !defined $state;
        say "Variable $i: ", $state;
    }
    exit;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please see attached screenshot to this code snippet if it is what you desired

```
!/usr/bin/perl
#
# vim: ai:ts=4:sw=4
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Tk;
use Data::Dumper;


my $main    = MainWindow->new( -title => 'Checkboxes' );
my $label   = $main->Label(-text => 'Presence Check');

$label->pack();

my $frame = $main->Frame(-relief=>'groove', -borderwidth=>2);

my $values;
my @chk_boxes = (
        [\$values->{doc_a},'Document A (docx, pdf)'],
        [\$values->{doc_b},'Document B (xlsx)'],
        [\$values->{spec_c},'C specification'],
        [\$values->{spec_a},'A-Specification'],
        [\$values->{report},'Important Report'],
        [\$values->{hand_b},'Handbook'],
        [\$values->{data_s},'Data Spreadsheet'],
        [\$values->{data_d},'D file'],
        [\$values->{doc_xx},'xx doc'],
        [\$values->{doc_yy},'yy Doc']
    );

check_box(\@chk_boxes);

$frame->pack();

my $button = $main->Button(
                -text => 'Exit',
                -command => \&exit_button
            );

$button->pack();

MainLoop();

sub exit_button {
    while( my($k,$v) = each %{$values} ) {
        say "$k => $v" if $v;
    }
    exit;
}

sub check_box {
    my $data = shift;

    my $index = 0;

    for my $chk_box ( @{$data} ) {
        my $column = $index % 2;
        my $row    = int($index/2);
        $frame->Checkbutton(
                -text       => $chk_box->[1],
                -variable   => $chk_box->[0]
                )->grid( -column => $column, -row => $row, -sticky => 'w');
        $index++;
    }
}
```

Perhaps following form of data input may be preferable

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# vim: ai:ts=4:sw=4
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Tk;
use Data::Dumper;


my $main    = MainWindow->new( -title => 'Checkboxes' );
my $label   = $main->Label(-text => 'Presence Check');

$label->pack();

my $frame = $main->Frame(-relief=>'groove', -borderwidth=>2);

my $values;
my @chk_boxes;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my($var,$desc) = split '\t';
    push @chk_boxes, [\$values->{$var}, $desc];
}

check_box(\@chk_boxes);

$frame->pack();

my $button = $main->Button(
                -text => 'Exit',
                -command => \&exit_button
            );

$button->pack();

MainLoop();

sub exit_button {
    while( my($k,$v) = each %{$values} ) {
        say "$k => $v" if $v;
    }
    exit;
}

sub check_box {
    my $data = shift;

    my $index = 0;

    for my $chk_box ( @{$data} ) {
        my $column = $index % 2;
        my $row    = int($index/2);
        $frame->Checkbutton(
                -text       => $chk_box->[1],
                -variable   => $chk_box->[0]
                )->grid( -column => $column, -row => $row, -sticky => 'w');
        $index++;
    }
}

__DATA__
doc_a   Document A (docx, pdf)
doc_b   Document B (xlsx)
spec_c  C specification
spec_a  A-Specification
report  Important Report
hand_b  Handbook
data_s  Data Spreadsheet
data_d  D file
doc_xx  xx Doc
doc_yy  yy Doc
```

Add-on:

```
sub check_box {
    my $data = shift;

    my $index = 0;

    for my $chk_box ( @{$data} ) {
        my $column = $index % 2;
        my $row    = int($index/2);
        my $chk_x = $frame->Checkbutton(
                -text       => $chk_box->[1],
                -variable   => $chk_box->[0]
                )->grid( -column => $column, -row => $row, -sticky => 'w');
        $chk_x->select if $index == 4;
        $index++;
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi @Polar Bear, I used your first answer and I found that the list of check allowed in the array chk_boxes is only 18 while I have roughly 50 list of checks. How should I able to list all the 50 checks? Much appreciate your comment

Comment: I tried your second suggestion and the gui seems without all the list text.

Comment: First column **must be separated with <TAB>** from rest of the string in `__DATA__` block.

Comment: First code snippet does not have any restriction on number of _records_ -- it is just array of array (AoA).

Comment: Okay, I just realized I have forgotten one comma after the value. Anyway, wish to know the reason you recommend second code snippet suggestion?

Comment: And not sure is this tk module has the ability to preset the check list? Means certain list of check is already checked when the GUI pop out. So that when user reopen the checkbox second time, it is able to restore the setting from first time. Just curious.

Comment: @Blurman -- second form is easier to type, number of keystrokes is significantly lower (also can be stored in external  _resource_ file).

Comment: @Blurman -- see documentation for [Tk::Checkbutton](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/pod/Checkbutton.pod). Particularly you are interested in **deselect** and **select** methods. Please see **Add-on** snippet code.

Comment: Thanks @Polar Bear. Another question, in your code, Line: say "$k => $v" if $v; how would you know if $v will be 1? I asked this because I would like to print other message like (Document A exist) when Document A is checked.

Comment: How should I write to add another line to print "$k => 0" if k is not being checked?

Comment: @Blurman -- you can use instead of `say "$k => $v" if $v;` following code line `say "$k => " . ($v ? 'present' : 'absent');`. In Tk form when you click checkbox it sets value into 1 otherwise it is undefined. Any value of  `0`, `undef` in if block considered `false` otherwise it considered `true`. A simple _if block_ has **ternary** form which is described on following [page](https://www.perl.com/article/20/2013/4/16/The-conditional-ternary-operator/). I recommend to read [webpage](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/modern_perl_a4.pdf) or type in Google **perl bookshelf**.